# Access Cross tab Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

[image]

I need to subtract the the number of items ordered from the quantity currently
recorded.

I can get the `count()` of the sales of each individual item like so:

```
SELECT SALES.PRODUCT_ID AS ORDERED_ID
         ,COUNT(SALES.PRODUCT_ID) AS ORDERED
   FROM SALES
   GROUP BY SALES.PRODUCT_ID
```

Which gives me:

```
ORDERED_ID  ORDERED
1201    2
1202    2
1204    2
1205    3
1206    1
1207    2
1208    1
1209    1
1210    3
```

Getting the quantity is just a matter of

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID AS INVEN_ID
         ,PRODUCT.QUANTITY AS INVEN
    FROM PRODUCT
```

Which gives me:

```
INVEN_ID    INVEN
1199    5
1200    2
1201    33
1202    44
1203    55
1204    66
1205    77
1206    88
1207    99
1208    110
1209    121
1210    132
```

I've spent hours on this problem and gave up at what I thought should be the solution:

```
SELECT SUB1.INVEN - SUB2.ORDERED
FROM 
 (SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID AS INVEN_ID
         ,PRODUCT.QUANTITY AS INVEN
    FROM PRODUCT
 )AS SUB1
,(SELECT SALES.PRODUCT_ID AS ORDERED_ID
         ,COUNT(SALES.PRODUCT_ID) AS ORDERED
   FROM SALES
   GROUP BY SALES.PRODUCT_ID
  )AS SUB2
  INNER JOIN SUB1 ON SUB1.INVEN_ID = SUB2.ORDERED_ID
```

However, access does not recognize that last join as a valid join and without it I just get a Cartesian product. If I try to retrieve `quantity` without a sub query and just try to `SELECT product.quantity - SUB2.ORDERED` access demands that I put `product.quantity - SUB2.ORDERED` in an aggregate function. When I do what it says it then tells me that `product.quantity - SUB2.ORDERED` can't be in an aggregate function. I'm at a loss.

EDIT:

```
Final Solution:

SELECT SUB1.INVEN_ID AS PRODUCT_ID
       ,SUB1.PRODUCT_NAME AS PRODUCT_NAME
       ,SUB1.PRICE AS PRICE
       ,SUB1.INVEN - NZ(SUB2.ORDERED,0) AS AVAILABLE
FROM 
 (SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID AS INVEN_ID
         ,PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME AS PRODUCT_NAME
         ,PRODUCT.PRICE AS PRICE
         ,PRODUCT.QUANTITY AS INVEN
    FROM PRODUCT
 )AS SUB1 
 LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT SALES.PRODUCT_ID AS ORDERED_ID
         ,COUNT(SALES.PRODUCT_ID) AS ORDERED
   FROM SALES
   GROUP BY SALES.PRODUCT_ID
  )AS SUB2 ON SUB1.INVEN_ID = SUB2.ORDERED_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INNER JOIN` should put after first subquery.

I think you are looking for `LEFT JOIN`,because `PRODUCT` table should be the master table.

if you use `LEFT JOIN` `SUB2.ORDERED` column might be NULL so use `NZ` function
Or `IIF(ISNULL(SUB2.ORDERED),0,SUB2.ORDERED)` to check.

You can try this.

```
SELECT SUB1.INVEN - NZ(SUB2.ORDERED,0)
FROM 
(SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID AS INVEN_ID
         ,PRODUCT.QUANTITY AS INVEN
    FROM PRODUCT
)AS SUB1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SALES.PRODUCT_ID AS ORDERED_ID
         ,COUNT(SALES.PRODUCT_ID) AS ORDERED
   FROM SALES
   GROUP BY SALES.PRODUCT_ID
)AS SUB2 ON SUB1.INVEN_ID = SUB2.ORDERED_ID
```

Comment: According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61) MS Access's isnull has one argument.

Comment: Other than that, this works pretty well. I'll monkey around with it more since I need to get a few more fields in it for a form to rely on the query but you broke a huge barrier for me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, My fail you can instead to use NZ function.thank for your remind:)